# Samsung ML 1670 printer refused to work under Big Sur

Tags: big-sur, printing, compatibility

I have an old Samsung ML 1670 laser printer which is often used when a bulk has to be printed.

It worked well on Catalina but after upgrading to Big Sur it is out of business.

Does anyone know if there is a workaround for this issue?

Comment: How exactly does it fail? What have you tried so far to solve the Problem?

Comment: It doesn't work at all.

Comment: That's rather broad. Does it not show up in the Printer settings in System Preferences, does it show up but any print job just hangs, or something else.

Answer (score 1):

Try to install https://support.apple.com/kb/dl905?locale=en_US drivers from Apple, then add new printer in Printers & Scanners panel. In the list of available drivers choose ML-1860 instead of ML-1670 and apply.

Comment: That doesn't work the printer drivers could not open bc it "doesn't meet the requirements"

Comment: "This download includes the latest Samsung printing and scanning software for OS X Mavericks, OS X Mountain Lion, OS X Lion and Mac OS X v10.6 Snow Leopard", make sense to get an error